# Error in ModelBuilder while all inputs are correct in the log

Tags: shapefile, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, 3d-analyst, las

So I made a simple ModelBuilder to create a shapefile from a LAS dataset. Without the inline variables it is working correctly. As shown in the log, all the inputs are correctly taken and when checking "Add to Display" the input layer is also shown in map view, however, for some reason I get the following errors.

Any idea what I am missing here?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please remember to always include text errors as text in the body of the Question. This assures that they are legible on all devices and searchable by others with the same issue. Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: Best practise is not to start folder names with numbers, contain spaces or hyphens, same with the dataset name. I would suggest you start there.

Comment: @Hornbydd The paths in the screenshot give me anxiety.

Comment: @Hornbydd Haha I know for this kind of processes it is not very useful, however, it provides good visibility in file managers. I will try it on a higher tree without does characters.